# Trigger an event after specific order of clicks

Tags: triggers, jquery

For a project I'm currently working on am trying to reach the following:

I have a simple page, on this page are 4, hidden and not visible  elements,
they are simply formatted as this:

```
<a href="#" class="link_1"></a>
<a href="#" class="link_2"></a>
<a href="#" class="link_3"></a>
<a href="#" class="link_4"></a>
```

Basically all i want, is too build a sort of Easter egg, so when a user clicks these buttons in a specific order, i.e. link_4 -> link_1 -> link_3 -> link_2
it triggers a certain event, whatever this might be.

Ofcourse the event could only be triggered if the right combination/order of clicks have been done.

Any ideas how to go about this using jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var click_order = [];
$('a').click(function (e) {
    click_order.push($(this).index());
    if (click_order.slice(-4) == '3,0,2,1') {
        // easter egg stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: That's it. Then you should reset the "click_order" variable if the order is already not satisfied :)

Comment: Brian, awesome example.  +1.  NOTE TO OP: In a broader environment, you'll have to put the links in a wrapper, and the selector should be `$('#wrapper a')` to preserve the proper order (rather than applying to all links on your page)

Comment: @EliseuMonar - No, you never have to reset `click_order` in the above example.

Comment: No need to really reset it, it's just an array of numbers, won't take up much memory as it's being added to. You would need thousands of clicks before it would even be marginally ineffective.

Comment: @Brian - More like hundreds of thousands on a modern machine.

Comment: Yea, an array of integers is nothing of note.

Comment: For some reason the comparison is returning false (in chrome).

Comment: Updated it, guess the if needs to compare against a string instead of another array. Verified it works with jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Ppggh/

Comment: I added a comparator to the prototype of Array to solve this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/gW7HE/2/

Comment: Well that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: It doesn't and it does. Non string/number comparison in javascript is very tricky. If you want to be absolutely sure there is no weirdness a better option than extending the prototype would be to do this: `if (click_order.slice(-4).join(',') == '3,0,2,1')`

Comment: Great stuff guys! The solution by Brian Cray works like a charm for our purpose...considering the buttons/links themselves won't be visible, it's highly unlikely that users are going to try and guess their way in.
Thanks a lot!!